# Replacing left logical shifts with other instructions in MIPS

Tags: mips

So let's say that we have two registers $s0 and $s1. Register $s0 can take values from 0 to 31 and is used to show how many bits register $s1 will be shifted left. How can i do this without using sll or srl. I know that left logical shift by n bits is the same as multiplying with 2^n. This exercise gives a hint that this can be done with 4 instructions only. Both registers are 32-bit.

Comment: Since its an exercise, why don't you start by showing us how you think you should approach this?

Comment: @ScottSeidman well since no shifts are allowed i am thinking about bit manipulation with NOR and AND.

Comment: And adding a number to itself is multiplying by two, or shifting left one bit. With a loop you could repeat the shift...

Answer (score 1):

The hint is right, you can do this all by multiplying.  The trick is realizing you use the value in $S0 as a counter.  No bit manipulation required.  I'll give you some code in C and let you translate it to MIPS assembly:

```
for (; $s0 > 0; $s0--)
{
    $s1 = $s1 + $s1;   // or $s1 = 2 * $s1
}
```